# Get Wallet balance from SeedPhrases

Tags: wallet, wallet-recovery, wallet-import-format

does anyone know how to get a Crypto wallet balance wit just SeedPhrase without having to log in to the account.

Answer (score 1):

Your mnemonic seed phrase is the secret that allows your bitcoin to be spent. You should be EXTREMELY careful with how you treat your seed phrase, as a mistake that exposes your seed phrase could mean that someone robs you of your funds.

In practice, this means you should only input your seed phrase into devices and software that you *fully* trust are secure. Do not ever input your seed phrase into a website, or share it with another person. Doing so is just asking to get robbed.

Any wallet that you use should show you your balance. Note that this is different than 'logging into an account' - a mnemonic seed phrase is *not* like your usual username/password. If you treat it as such, it is likely only a matter of time until you lose your funds. Really, you should endeavour to handle your seed phrase as little as possible.

Answer (score 1):

With bitcoin you do not "log in" to "an account".

If you are keeping a balance on an exchange, that is a normal login process, but nothing to do with your seed phrases.

If you mean the balance on a specific BTC address on the public blockchain, anyone can check that, visible to all, from many open websites, anybody's wallet-client, BTC nodes etc.

Seed phrase (+password) is for setting up a wallet-client, and as already mentioned is risky and should be rarely done. Ideally you only keep your private keys on a hardware wallet, and your software wallet-clients are by default Watch-Only without the HWW.

Thus how you "log in" to check your summarized account-wallet balances depends on your wallet-client.

Comment: But I am looking for a way to find the balance of a wallet without having to input my seedphrase in a wallet.

Comment: How do you mean "wallet" there the first time? The collection of addresses on the blockchain (account-wallet) have no outward connection to each other without a wallet-client that can derive all the key chains and derived wallet-accounts. As I stated, a Watch-Only wallet-client will do what you want - total up those thousands of addresses. The master extended public keys (xpub) may be enough, but that depends on the software wallet-client you use.